# Select a couple of rows having equal values in one column and different in another

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the test database which I have:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e501e/1

I want to execute a MySQL query to check if there is at least one couple of rows with different values for column **USERID** and same value for column **NUMBERID**. So in this example the result would be that:
[image]

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What would be the exact desired result? 2 arbitrary rows per numberid?

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*)
from   test a 
join   test b 
on     a.numberid = b.numberid 
and    a.userid != b.userid
```

This query will return you 2 x  the number of such pairs, so that's enough to tell whether any such pairs exist.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e501e/14

```
select x.*
  from test x
  join (select numberid
          from test
         where numberid <> userid
         group by numberid
        having count(*) > 1) y
    on x.numberid = y.numberid
 where x.numberid <> x.userid
```

Notice numberid 2 does not come back even though you enclosed it in red in your screenshot. That is because it only has one row where numberid is not equal to userid. In your screenshot if you look at the second row for numberid that you identified, numberid is actually equal to the userid, 2. So that row does not count towards the 2+ requirement you stated.

And numberid 1 is coming back but for a different reason, in your test data on sql fiddle, you have an additional row (1, 3), which when added with (1, 2), makes numberid 1 meet the 2+ requirement. With just (1, 1) and (1, 2) it would not meet the requirement, because only (1, 2) is different.